# Plotly choropleth works in online but not offline mode

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to recreate [Plotly's county choropleth example](https://plot.ly/python/county-choropleth/) in offline mode. The example works fine when passing my credentials to the plot online:

```
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fips = ['06021', '06023', '06027',
        '06029', '06033', '06059',
        '06047', '06049', '06051',
        '06055', '06061']
values = range(len(fips))
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='MaxGhenis', 
                                  api_key=KEY)
fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
plotly.plotly.iplot(fig, filename='online choropleth')
```

But when it's offline it doesn't show up:

```
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='offline choropleth')
```

I'm using [Google's Colaboratory cloud Jupyter service](http://colab.research.google.com) (here's the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1T3WgAhyJZBddpAK5z3K3d2laUhH_zgKq#scrollTo=lNk1uSxI0PGu)). Any ideas how to fix this?

Update: Filed https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1045.